# React Native Pass properties on goBack in react-navigation ?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use `react-navigation` with `StackNavigatior` to navigate through screens. I navigate from the screen A to screen B where I can select one option from a list of options.

After I press Done, I want to go back to screen A and see what option I selected in screen B.

How can I do that ?

I tried to pass the option selected to `goBack()` method, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If screen A is a parent of screen B, you can pass something like:

```js
    setScreenBOption: function (option) {
        this.setState({screenBOption:option});
    }
```

to screen B.

Then from screen B whenever the option is selected, you can call

```js
    this.props.setScreenBOption(thingThatWasClicked);
```

On screen A, you'd display `this.state.screenBOption`.

If screen A and screen B are siblings, you'd add the `setScreenBOption` function onto the parent of screen A and screen B and pass `this.setScreenBOption` down to screen B and `this.state.screenBOption` to screen A. On screen A, you'd display `this.props.screenBOption`.

Comment: Thx. I pass a function to props.navigation.navigate, and the i called that function in screen B. You saved my day. Thx man